# Adding top only border to UIToolBar in Swift

Tags: swift, uitoolbar

I am trying to add a top only border to a UIToolBar with define color.Currently, I am using the following code to give a transparent look.ToolBar looks ok.But, I am getting a black top border line in the toolBar.I want to change that black border to white.

```
    My Code:
    navigationController?.toolbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: UIBarPosition.any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.default)
    navigationController?.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    navigationController?.toolbar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.toolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.6, alpha: 0.2)

    // To remove the black border line. If, I want to
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.clipsToBounds = true


   // I don't want to put a border around the UIToolbar like below code
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.layer.borderWidth = 0.2
```

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: mytabbr.bounds.minX, y: mytabbr.bounds.minY ))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: mytabbr.bounds.maxX, y: mytabbr.bounds.minY ))

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()

    shape.path = path.cgPath
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shape.lineWidth = 2
    shape.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

    mytabbr.layer.addSublayer(shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just Figure it out the answer.Simply , I placed a hairline UIView just above my toolBar.

```
  let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:view.frame.width, height:0.2))
  lineView.backgroundColor=UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
  self.navigationController?.toolbar.addSubview(lineView)
```

I used the below code to remove the black existing borderline from the toolBar

```
 self.navigationController?.toolbar.clipsToBounds = true
```

Above code works and looks great.Any, Improved answer will be appreciated....